# Drupal Ubercart migration to Virtuemart

Tags: drupal, joomla, virtuemart, ubercart

I'm trying to migrate a wholly functional Drupal/Ubercart based webshop to a VirtueMart shop.

Now I'm very familiar with VirtueMart and Joomla, but not so much with Drupal.

My question is where does Drupal/Ubercart hold the product CATEGORIES?

Because I see that ubercart has a table for products and orders, but I'm looking for the product categories as well, I just cant find them.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be possible that the Drupal website uses taxonomy to organize their products into categories.  If so you could find those in the taxonomy table.